# How to get the parameterized type of an instance with Dart and smoke?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Consider this code:

```dart
class Foo {
  List<String> listOfStrings;
}
```

Using the [smoke](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/smoke/0.2.1/index.html#smoke/smoke) package, how can I get `String` by looking at `listOfStrings` ?

I see we can get a `Declaration` from a `Type`, but I don't see how to get the parameterized type from [Declaration](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/smoke/0.2.1/index.html#smoke/smoke.Declaration).

This is important for, among other things, building a serialization library.

Comment: This is impossible. The `smoke` does not collect such kind of the data and, thus, does not provide possibility to get this information. This is possible only through `mirrors`. Also you tagged this question as a `dart-mirrors` but this is not correct because the `smoke` is not a reflection such a `dart:mirrors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not currently possible to do in smoke.

It might not even be possible to do with the mirrors API directly either. For example:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
class B<T> {}
class A {
  static B<int> b = new B<int>();
}
main() {
  var x = reflectType(A);
  print(x);
  print(x.declarations[#b].type);
}
```

will print `B`, but not `B<int>`.

Comment: This is possible with `dart:mirrors`. You have to test your knowledge.  `print((x.declarations[#b] as VariableMirror).type.typeArguments);`

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's not possible w/ smoke today. We've opened https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20584 in the meantime.